# checkboxGroupButton - Select one at a time

Tags: r, shiny, data-science, shinywidgets

I'm trying to create a radiobutton in the style of the checkboxGroupButton() in R shiny.

I want to recreate this example with the same button aesthetics, but only allow the user to select one input at a time.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("checkboxGroupButtons examples"),
  
  checkboxGroupButtons(
    inputId = "somevalue1",
    label = "Make a choice: ",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C")
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("value1")
)
  
 

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$value1 <- renderPrint({ input$somevalue1 })

  
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can mark a question as solved by accepted a proposed answer. If none of the provided answers work for you, feel free to post your own solution. Do not edit your question to include a solution. The community will decide which answer it likes best by voting.

Comment: No worries - where can I post my own solutions? (apologies, am still new to SO)

Comment: You can post an answer below your question just like any other post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - can simply be solved by replacing the `checkboxGroupButtons()` function with `radioGroupButtons()`

Answer (score 0):

To create a radiobutton with the same button aesthetics as the checkboxGroupButton() function in R shiny, you can use the radioButtons() function. This function allows you to create a group of radio buttons that the user can select from, but only allows the user to select one option at a time.

So this means it would look something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Radiobutton examples"),
  
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "somevalue1",
    label = "Make a choice: ",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C")
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("value1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {  
  output$value1 <- renderPrint({ input$somevalue1 })
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Or if you really want to use the checkboxes, then use the argument "selectize = TRUE", for instance, immediately bellow your argument "choices".

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time in replying. Unfortunately this isn't what I am looking for. These are radiobuttons, and do what I want, but the aesthetic is different. They need to look exactly the same as checkboxGroupButtons - group of horizontal square boxes that only allow for one selection.

Comment: Try to use the "selectize = TRUE" argument inside checkboxGroupButtons, for instance, immediately bellow your "choices". It should do what you are looking for. :)

Comment: doesn't work, met with error:
``` 
Error in checkboxGroupButtons(inputId = "somevalue1", label = "Make a choice: ",  : 
  unused argument (selectize = TRUE)
```

Comment: That's much probably because your shinyWidgets package version is inferior to v0.5.0. Please try to update and it will work.

Comment: I have version 0.7.5 - will try rolling back to v0.5.0

Comment: Same error - it appears that checkboxGroupButtons simply does not support the selectize argument

Comment: I wish I could help you further but I really can't understand why it does not work, it should. There must be something else messing with that. :(

Comment: It's because the selectize argument isn't supported by the checkboxGroupButtons function - it's not coded for it.